# How to return to command prompt after a silent NSIS install

Tags: cmd, nsis, silent-installer

I have a requirement for my silent installer to return to the command prompt after successful completion. Currently the best I can do is get to a blinking underscore. I must then manually hit the enter key.

Thank you.

Comment: How about showing us some code? Do you have anything special going on? Are you writing to stdout in the installer?

Answer (score 1):

NSIS installers are GUI applications and cmd.exe should not wait for them at all.

```
RequestExecutionLevel user
Outfile "Test.exe"
SilentInstall silent
Name "Test"

Section
System::Call 'user32::MessageBeep(i0)'
Sleep 3333
System::Call 'user32::MessageBeep(i0)'
SectionEnd
```

This little sample returns control to the console immediately without having to press anything. (Both `test` and `call test`, `start /WAIT test` will wait of course). Compiled with NSIS 2.46 and 3.0 trunk and tested in cmd.exe on Win8.

*Edit:*

You failed to mention that you are writing to stdout from NSIS. Doing that is a bit of a hack since the installer is not a console application. Because cmd.exe thinks it is running a GUI application it does not wait and then when the GUI application calls AttachConsole you end up with two applications thinking they are in control of stdout and things no longer work 100% correctly.

If you execute `yourapp.exe&dir /S /B c:\` the things written to stdout by yourapp.exe is going to get lost somewhere in the output from dir! In your case the prompt (usually current-directory + `>`) is actually printed but it happens before yourapp.exe's output so that's why it looks like you just have a blinking cursor.

I was **unable** to come up with a solution that actually does what you want:

```
SilentInstall silent

Function WriteCommandLine 
System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0'
System::Call 'kernel32::AttachConsole(i -1)'
StrCmp $0 0 "" +2
System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0'
FileWrite $0 $R1
FileWrite $0 $\n
/* Does not work: 
System::Call 'kernel32::FreeConsole()'
*/
/* This ugly hack does not work:
ExpandEnvStrings $0 "%COMSPEC%"
StrCmp $0 "" "" +2
StrCpy $0 cmd.exe
Exec '"$0" /c prompt' 
*/
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
strcpy $R1 "Hello World"
call WriteCommandLine
FunctionEnd
```

If your installer is always silent you could use `!packhdr` if you can find a tool that can change IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI to IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI in a PE file...

Comment: Thank you but that code just beeps 2x and still leaves me with a blinking underscore...

Comment: Here is what I am doing:                                         Function .onInstSuccess
   !ifdef DebuggingScript
      StrCpy $R1 "FUNCTION onInstSuccess"
      Call WriteCommandLine
   !endif
   IfSilent InstSuccess_SILENT InstSuccess_GUI

InstSuccess_SILENT:
   !ifdef DebuggingScript
      StrCpy $R1 "FUNCTION onInstSuccess_SILENT!!"
      Call WriteCommandLine
   !endif   
   
   System::Call 'user32::MessageBeep(i0)';
   Sleep 3333
   System::Call 'user32::MessageBeep(0xffffffff)';
      
   Quit
   
InstSuccess_GUI:                                                    FunctrionEnd

Comment: Sorry for the above mess... What happened to my formatting!

Comment: Anyway, all I really need is to return to the command prompt after finished with a silent install (DOS in my case...) C:\The installer dir>                                                                              Is it even possible?

Comment: And what is WriteCommandLine? If you are writing to stdout then that changes things...

Comment: (something I found somewhere on nsis.sourceforge.net some time back...                                                             Function WriteCommandLine    System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0' 
   System::Call 'kernel32::AttachConsole(i -1)' 
   FileWrite $0 $R1
   FileWrite $0 $\n
   
     
FunctionEnd

Comment: Thank you for the "under-the-hood" info re nsis. I have a requirement to give the user some type of indication as to the progress of our silent install, hence the need for the WriteCommandLine function. Other clients prefer the gui, so one installer with both gui and silent install capability is what we use. If you have a different or better method for writing to the command line, I will gladly change my code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the installer yourself, and do you want to wait for the installer to finish?

In that case, call the following:

```
start /wait YourInstaller.exe /S
```